# Can I turn off the interactive piece of Xaml and keep the layout management?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, xps, documentpage

I am working on rendering XPS documents in a WCF service and want it to be as fast as possible.

**Is it possible to turn off any UI related overhead, since there is no UI interaction necessary in my use case?** I want to just utilize the UI layout management piece of Xaml. Basically, how can I turn off anything unnecessary to the creation of a document?

When I'm done rendering, I'm adding each `FrameworkElement` to a `DocumentPage`s to be rendered with a `DocumentPaginator` and then saving that to an XPS using the `XpsDocumentWriter`.

Comment: I don't think your service would be receiving any UI notifications. Does you service use Application.Run()?

Comment: Correct, it doesn't receive any UI notifications because it is a web service, so if there's any event wiring, or additional overhead by Xaml that I can turn off, that's what I'm looking to do. While I'm building out the visual tree, I want there to be as little overhead as possible.

Comment: I know what the intent of your service is, what I am saying is that I don't think there would be a message loop running to receive UI events. Do you use the method Application.Run()?

Comment: No, I never call Application.Run

Comment: I do pump the message queue once to achieve page number binding though.

Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher.Invoke(DispatcherPriority.SystemIdle, new DispatcherOperationCallback(delegate { return null; }), null);

Comment: Then you are fine. Your service is not processing Windows messages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just make sure you don't call `Application.Run` in your service and there will be no message loop processing Windows messages.